# Translate FOSOAuthServerBundle errors

Tags: symfony

Is there any way to translate FOSOAuthServerBundle error messages, such as "Invalid username and password combination"?

I've tried to create messages.de.yml file under app/Resources/translations directory and put this lines:

```
Invalid username and password combination: "Falsche E-Mail / Passwort Kombination"
```

and set `locale: de` in app/config/parameters.yml, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the message you are tring to translate is hard coded ( [see this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/337) ) You need to override this methods to add translations